# Bind visibility to multiple properties and update it

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

There is a `datagrid` with `datarows` and `master-details` format.

**Property1** - selected value of a combobox

**Property2** and **Property3** another properties from a different classes which are not observable collections.

So I made binding that way, but now I can't figure out how to trigger an update of datarow visibility when `Property1` changed.

If I click a button to hide "detail" rows and expand them again I see a result that I need:

"Previous rows has been hidden and new ones has been shown depend on a new value of Property1"

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type xcdg:DataRow}}" TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>                
        <DataTrigger Value="Hide">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myVisibleConverter}" >
                    <Binding Path="Property1" />
                    <Binding Path="Property2" />
                    <Binding Path="Property3" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I don't understand very well what you want to achieve....

Comment: well combobox is a filter, for example, show only rows with property2 is true, or only property3 is true. So datagrid has all row and when i change combobox selectedvalue(property1) i want to see rows visibility changing in real time

Comment: Did you try using another approach? Using for example the CollectionViewSource functionality? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control

Comment: yeap, but it works only with master view and doesnt see detail rows

Comment: Try posting some more code so we can discover if there is an alternative.